# jquery script works only one time

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I need your help please. I have this jquery script that works but only one time. The second time it doesn't work until i refresh the page. To be more accurate, the second time "it works" until it reaches the second alert. The second time it doesn't fire up the modal. Before posting I googled for an answer and from what I understood it is related to bind method. i tried to figure out what's going on before asking for help but I wasn't able to figure it out by myself.

This is the html page:

```
<div class="container bkoffice-n-immobile bg-light">

  <div class='row' id='rw-master'>

    <div class='col-md-12'>
      <div class='row p-4'>
        <div class='col-md-2 col-thumbnail'>
          <div class='card'>
            <img class='card-img-top' src='../' alt= '' >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-8 p-2 col-img'>
          <p><b>Rif.:</b><span class='ps-5'>b 12</span></p>
          <p><b>Tipologia:</b><span class='ps-2'>monolocale</span></p>
          <p><b>Indirizzo:</b><span class='ps-2'></span></p>
          <p><b>Prezzo:</b><span class='ps-4'>€ 0</span></p>
          <div class='row rw-img'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
              <i class='fas fa-eye' title='visualizzazioni'></i>
              <span class='p-2'>0</span>
              <a href='m-immobile.php?id=194'class='mod-imm' rel='194'><i class='fas fa-edit icon' title='modifica'></i></a>
              <a href='#' class='del-imm' rel='194'><i class='fas fa-trash icon' title='cancella'></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class='form-check form-switch mt-2'>
              <input class='form-check-input chkvisibile' type='checkbox' value='1' rel='194'>
              <label class='form-check-label'>Ann. Visibile</label>
            </div>

            <div class='form-check form-switch'>
              <input class='form-check-input chkpagina' type='checkbox' value='1' rel='194'>
              <label class='form-check-label'>Ann. Prima Pagina</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div class='row p-4'>
          <div class='col-md-2 col-thumbnail'>
            <div class='card'><img class='card-img-top' src='../' alt= '' ></div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-8 p-2 col-img'>
            <p><b>Rif.:</b><span class='ps-5'>b 800</span></p>
            <p><b>Tipologia:</b><span class='ps-2'>monolocale</span></p>
            <p><b>Indirizzo:</b><span class='ps-2'></span></p>
            <p><b>Prezzo:</b><span class='ps-4'>€ 0</span></p>
            <div class='row rw-img'>
              <div class='col-md-12'>
                <i class='fas fa-eye' title='visualizzazioni'></i>
                <span class='p-2'>0</span>
                <a href='m-immobile.php?id=193'class='mod-imm' rel='193'><i class='fas fa-edit icon' title='modifica'></i></a>
                <a href='#' class='del-imm' rel='193'><i class='fas fa-trash icon' title='cancella'></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class='form-check form-switch mt-2'>
                <input class='form-check-input chkvisibile' type='checkbox' value='1' rel='193'>
                <label class='form-check-label'>Ann. Visibile</label>
              </div>
              <div class='form-check form-switch'>
                <input class='form-check-input chkpagina' type='checkbox' value='1' rel='193'>
                <label class='form-check-label'>Ann. Prima Pagina</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- MODAL START HERE -->

        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mdl-avviso-imm">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"><b><u>Progetto Casa</u></b></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Sicuro di voler cancellare questo immobile?, l'operazione è irreversibile!!!
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="del-btn-imm" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancella</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-bg-v" id="dismiss" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annulla</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

   <!-- MODAL END HERE -->
```

this is the jquery script:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).unbind('click').on('click', '.del-imm', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("click");
      var id = $(this).closest(".del-imm").attr('rel');
      data_1 = 'id=' + id;
      alert(id);
      alert(data_1);
      $('#mdl-avviso-imm').modal('show');
      $('#del-btn-imm').on('click', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();       
          $.ajax({
            url: 'php/del-imm-new.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: data_1,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
              $('#rw-master').html("");
              $('#rw-master').html(html);
            }
          });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Just before `$('#mdl-avviso-imm').modal('show');` add `console.log($('#mdl-avviso-imm').length);`    Does your modal still exist the second time around?  Depends on where `#rw-master` is and whether it blats the modal or not.  (also, better to use console.log rather than `alert` as that can have side-effects)

Comment: my guess is you deleted the modal from the page

Comment: thanks for the reply. The second time, from the console, i have a zero 0 number adding console.log($('#mdl-avviso-imm').length);

Comment: @freedomn-m the modal is after the #rw-master and php script works/operate inside the rw-master div recreating the list. I don't know if the command: $('#rw-master').html(""); and  $('#rw-master').html(html); delete everything that is inside the rw-master and also after the rw-master div

Comment: Please post the part INCLUDING the DIV with **id** rw-master in your HTML

Comment: `.unbind` is deprecated (as per the documentation). The opposite function for `.on` is `.off` (again as per the documentation)

Comment: @KenLee thanks, I edited the post because a line was missing due to the parser of the page

Comment: Are those two sections of code you've shown continuous in reality? Also the indentation isn't quite right, so it's hard to see what things are inside others. I wonder if you need to edit the code formatting a bit more...

Comment: @ADyson Yes, it is all one after the other. I have problem to indent everything correctly here on stackoverflow (my apologies)

Comment: I think I fixed it for you (if you go back into edit mode now, you can see how it was done)

Comment: Essentially: the .length log shows you that the modal is no longer there on the second time.  So you need to determine exactly why.  Try removing the 2x .html("")/.html(html) calls - if the modal is still there with those missing, then they're the cause.  Otherwise it's somewhere else.

Comment: Based on what you've shown, the modal is within the `rw-master` div (it starts after the end of the first `<div class='col-md-12'>`). So replacing the contents of that div will destroy the modal.

Comment: This means that the HTML returned by the AJAX call doesn't include the modal. Perhaps it shouldn't be inside the `rw-master` DIV in the first place.

Comment: As above: putting your code into a [parser](https://jsfiddle.net/bsn8of7k/) shows two missing divs at the end at the modal inside the rw-master.  This might be just how the code is currently formatted / due to edits.   So take your *rendered* code and put it in an html-formatter to see what it says

Comment: Indeed, if we show freedomn-m's fiddle with the closing `</div>`s removed again, JSFiddle will highlight the error at the end of the markup: https://jsfiddle.net/bhv1otga/ . Always use an editor with good HTML support.

Comment: Try adding `</div></div>` BEFORE `<!-- MODAL START HERE -->` and re-try

Comment: @all
thanks for all the info i need to check the returned code of the ajax code and see if everything is fine. I'll keep you updated, I just need a while to check the code.

Comment: @KenLee that was the problem in the end. After checking and trying, the problem where the two missing div. thanks and thanks to all!

Comment: In the future if you have a solution, please post an answer and accept it to resolve the question. Otherwise, please delete the question.